# Why is BufferedReader skipping some lines when reading a PHP file?

Tags: java, inputstream, readfile

I'm writing a function in Java to read a PHP line by line. I noticed some of lines are skipped.

Function in Java:

```
 public String ReadContentRegex(String path, String Regex) throws
 FileNotFoundException, IOException
     {
         final StringBuilder contents = new StringBuilder();

         BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(

         new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(path)));

         try {
             String line;

             while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                 System.out.println(br.readLine());

             }
         } finally {
             br.close();
         }

         return contents.toString();

     }
```

A PHP file that Java should read using `BufferedReader`:

```
<?php #if (!APP_ACT) exit();

class dbtest extends Codeplexon\core\fwcontroller {

public $name = __CLASS__;

    static function destruct()
{
    // ili 404
    echo("Error function: ".__FUNCTION__);
}

public function db()
{       
        $model = new Codeplexon\model\fwmodel;
        $model->db->load();
        #$e = $model->db->count();
        $model->db->select();
        $model->db->from("db");
        $model->db->query();
        $a = $model->db->fetch();
        #$num_rows = $model->db->numrows();
        #$lastquery = $model->db->lastquery();

        var_dump($a);
}
    //etc....
```

Incorrect output:

```
class dbtest extends Codeplexon\core\fwcontroller {

        // ili 404

            $model = new Codeplexon\model\fwmodel;
            $model->db->select();
            $a = $model->db->fetch();


            $model = new Codeplexon\model\fwmodel;
            $obj = array("val" => substr(md5(time()), 0, 10));
        }
        {
            $model->db->load();
            $model->db->where("id", "5");

            $model = new Codeplexon\model\fwmodel;
            $r = $model->db->querycustom('SELECT * FROM a_mvcdb.db WHERE id = 4');

        }
        {
```

I think there is a problem with return statement `.toString()` or class name `public String ReadContentRegex(String path, String Regex)` but I'm not sure what's wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are calling `readLine()` twice.

You read a line and store it in the String variable `line`:

```
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
```

Then you disregard what you read and you read *another* line inside of your println statement.

```
System.out.println(br.readLine());
```

Change the above line to

```
System.out.println(line);
```

Comment: Result is same if I change like this             while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                
                Matcher zr = p.matcher(line);
                
                System.out.println(line);

Comment: Are you certain?  Based on your code, that double `readLine()` call is exactly what I'd go by as your problem as well.

Comment: The problem is also that you are returning a StringBuffer you never put anything inside of. Not sure why I was downvoted.

Comment: Hunter's right; you're also not using the `contents` Object.  I suspect that you posted your testing code while trying to figure out your problem, rather than your actual concatenation code.

Comment: JoshDM, you are right. You solved my question. Changing `contents` to `con` solved missed lines of readed file.